# PieChart legend displaying only 1 of the 12 categories plotted in MP Android Chart

Tags: android-studio, mpandroidchart

I have used piechart from MPandroidchart before and the legend used to be generated automatically. For a new app I am developing, using the same code results in a graph with only one entry in the legend instead of 12. Following is my code snippet:

private void setupPieChart() {

```
List<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < spend.length; i++) {
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(spend[i], categories[i]));
}
PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "Spend Areas");
PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
data.setValueTextSize(10);

PieChart chart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);
chart.setData(data);
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

chart.invalidate();
dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
chart.animateXY(5000, 5000);
```

I have also tried setting custom legends in the following way:

```
Legend l = chart.getLegend();
l.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
l.setTextSize(10f);
l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE);
l.setFormSize(10f);
l.setXEntrySpace(5f);
l.setFormToTextSpace(10f);


   LegendEntry[] legendEntries=new LegendEntry[12];
    for(int i=0;i<legendEntries.length;i++)
    {
        LegendEntry entry=new LegendEntry();
        entry.formColor=MY_COLORS[i];
        entry.label=categories[i];
        legendEntries[i]=(entry);

    }
l.setCustom(legendEntries);
```

This works if I put the number of legend entries as 2. For any number more than 2, the app crashes with the following error:

```
Process: com.javahelps.mylifeapp, PID: 11444
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LegendRenderer.renderLegend(LegendRenderer.java:377)
at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart.onDraw(PieChart.java:141)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21594)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20471)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4397)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4370)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20431)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4397)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4370)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20431)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21326)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4413)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4174)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20462)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21326)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4413)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4174)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20462)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21326)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4413)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4174)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20462)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21326)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4413)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4174)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21597)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:813)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20471)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:580)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:586)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:659)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3870)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3670)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1929)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7987)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1154)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:977)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:893)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1139)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Has anyone faced any similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue lies in the following line:

```
entry.label=categories[i];
```

You can check by setting break point on this point. The loop is running 12 times but categories[] size is less than 12. you need to replace following line:

```
for(int i=0;i<legendEntries.length;i++)
```

with:

```
for(int i=0;i<pieEntries.size();i++)
```

also you need to do following:

```
LegendEntry[] legendEntries=new LegendEntry[pieEntries.size()];
```

This is because the legend will be equal to the number of entries you have in your chart. By doing this legend will be created for each entry and your issue will be resolved. Best of luck!